# Email Subdomains cannot start or end with a hyphen, nor have two in a row

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a situation in which email domain need to pass below scenarios

Domain:

- Domain can be made up by subdomains separated by a period.
- Each subdomain must have at least 2 characters.
- Subdomains can be alphanumeric and can include hyphens.
- Subdomains cannot start or end with a hyphen, nor have two in a row.

Not Accepted subdomain

- foobar@-fear.com
- foobar@fear-.com
- foobar@fear.com-
- foobar@fear.co--m
- foobar@f.com
- foobar@fear.c

Accepted

- foobar@fea-r.com
- foobar@fear.co-m
- foo-bar@fear.com
- foo----bar@fear.com
- foobar-@fear.com

Example:

```
Email- foobar@mahi.co.in
Username - foobar
Domain - mahi.co.in


var emailIdExp = ^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)*[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-]{2,}$
```

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: I am trying for regular expression in which subdomain of email should not start or end with hyphen and there should not be two consecutive hyphens in subdomain

Comment: This is a requirement - not a question.  What part of this requirement do you have problems with and why?

Comment: how to implement 4th point in my expression. i was able to reach /^[A-Za-z0-9._-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.)*[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-]{2,}$/

Comment: What is the expected result for `foo-bar@fear.com`?

Comment: Accepted. All rules of regex are applied on subdomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
^[\w.-]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+([-]?[A-Za-z0-9]+)+([\.][A-Za-z0-9]+([-]?[A-Za-z0-9]+)+)+$
```

The above regex is updated here : https://regex101.com/r/7P4XWM/3

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with that regex:

```
^[\w-_\.]+@\w+(-\w+)*(\.\w+(-\w+)*)+$
```

Example:
https://regex101.com/r/7P4XWM/1

With that, the following condition is not fulfilled, though:

- Each subdomain must have at least 2 characters.

Comment: According to OP updates, both `foo-bar@fear.com` and `foo----bar@fear.com` should match.

Comment: @PM77-1 yes it is passing. Only constraint is now at least 2 characters one is failing.